# Как переключаться между узлами Firebase?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sdk, firebase

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь. Как переключаться между узлами в Firebase? Есть календарь, на определенную дату свой узел в бд. Текущий список отображает без проблем. Но когда выбираю другую дату список не обновляется. Помогите, как это  реализовать?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<UserModel> result;
private UserAdapter adapter;

CalendarView calendarView;
String selectedDate;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_password);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    selectedDate = sdf.format(date);
    try {
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                int mYear = year;
                int mMonth = month;
                int mDay = dayOfMonth;
                selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mDay).append("_").append(mMonth + 1).append("_")
                        .append(mYear).toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reference = database.getReference(selectedDate);
                           }
        });
       database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference(selectedDate);

        result = new ArrayList<>();


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);


        adapter = new UserAdapter(result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        updateList();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }


}
private void updateList() {

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //  result.clear();
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.set(index, model);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private int getItemIndex(UserModel user) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(user.key))
            index = i;
        break;
    }
    return index;
}
```

}
введите сюда описание изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо скринов кода. Код надо текстом. Просто замены ссылку не достаточно - надо переназначить слушатели обновлений данных

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как это реализовать,подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в колбэке изменения даты менять не только ссылку на ноду в БД, но и убрать все данные из их списка, уведомить адаптер о изменениях данных, и назначить новый слушатель изменения данных.

По хорошему, при изменении ссылки на ноду, надо бы ещё и убрать со старой слушатели.

Т.е., в конце слушателя изменения даты, вместо `reference = database.getReference(selectedDate);` надо так:

```
result.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

reference.removeChangeListeners();
reference = database.getReference(selectedDate);
updateList();
```

Comment: Прошу прощение за глупый вопрос ,но у  меня эту строчку подчеркивает красным 
reference.removeChangeListeners()

Comment: Значит она немного по другому называется. Посмотрите в доке

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)))не много подкоректирывал и все работает)